# Find out how many balls after 4 hours algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

*Question*

In a box, each ball is being divided by a second for half hour.

At 9 in the morning, there were 10,000 balls.

A. How many balls will we have at 14 oo (2)?
B. how many balls did we have in the same morning at 7?

This is the question, I'm sitting on it for like half hour now and I can't find a way to solve it. How?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- At 09:30 you have $20000$ balls, at 10:00 you have $40000$, at 10:30 you have $80000$, and so on
- At 08:30 you had $5000$ balls, at 08:00 you had $2500$ and so on

Comment: But this is ridiculous because it says that the answer for A is 10,240,000?

Comment: Indeed $10^{5 \times 2} = 1024$.  Perhaps they are very small balls